# I am getting a date of "598146673" when I use JSONEncoder with a Date type

Tags: swift, django, xcode, jsonencoder

Title says it all. I don't mind getting the date as "598146673" but I just need to convert it when I receive that on my Django. Ideally, I would like to what format it is or how I can have xcode leave it in "2019-12-15 23:51:13 +0000"

Comment: Your date value it is the time interval the date and the reference date `January 1st 2001 at UTC` `Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 598146673)  // "Dec 15, 2019 at 8:51 PM"`

Comment: If you are decoding it using JSONDecoder that's the default date decoding strategy `.deferredToDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom encoding to send the date to your Django service as a formatted string, like this:

```
struct MyDjangoRequest: Encodable {

    let myDate: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case myDate = "myDate"
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +0000"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        let myFormattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: myDate)

        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(myFormattedDate, forKey: .myDate)
    }
}

//encode your request
let r = MyDjangoRequest(myDate: Date())
let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(r)

//have a look at it!
let s = String(data: json!, encoding: .utf8). 
//      "{"myDate":"2019-12-04 03:38:28 +0000"}"
```

Comment: This is a lot more helpful than I was hoping for haha. Thank you